# What is the name of mathematical object similar to a graph, but with different kind of edges?

Tags: graph-theory, mathematical-modeling

While modeling biochemical networks in the cell using Lisp programming language, I recognized that I use a certain model for this task. This model resembles a directed graph, with edges pointed not only to vertices but sometimes to other edges.

I wonder is there any distinct name for this kind of model in mathematics?

Here is a simple example of the model pictured in a graph-like way.
[image]

Comment: I guess it can still be treated like a directed graph?

Comment: How?  It has an edge without two vertices.

Comment: Yes, just like matrices that can be treated as weighted graphs, but which actually are standalone mathematical objects.

To treat this structure as a directed graph I should add extra vertices and break some edges into the parts. (In a true graph edges can connect only vertices)

I wouldn't like to do this, as it eliminates the clarity of the model, where vertices corresponds only to the physical entities like molecules, and each edge means either a biochemical reaction (e.g. e1 and e2) or biochemical regulation (e.g. e3 as catalysis).

Comment: What is the difference in meaning from a directed graph where all the arrows go to vertices?  In this case it seems the e4 arrow could just leave v2 and go back, while the e3 arrow goes from v4 to v2.

Answer (score 3):

Mathematically spoken a (directed) graph is a set of vertices, say, $V=\{a,b,c\}$ 
and a set of (ordered) pairs of this vertices, say, $\{(a,b),(a,c),(c,b)\}$, 
The pairs are called edges (or in the directed graph, arcs), and are sometimes 
abbreviated by (as in your case) $e1$, etc.

But it is not prohibitted, that the set of vertices contains 
semantically different things, like "simple" vertices, and
ordered pairs of simple vertices, and pairs of ordered pairs and so on. 
Everything can be a vertex.

In your case the vertex set would be $V=\{v1, v2, v3, v4, (v1,v2), (v2, v3), (v4, (v1,v2))\}$,
where I indicate an ordered pair by $(.. , ..)$.
You see I avoided totally the notion $e3$ etc., 
since these would be only abbreviations for ordered pairs.
The arc set for your example is then 
$E=\{(v1,v2), (v4, (v1,v2)), (v2,v3), ((v2,v3),(v4,(v1,v2)))\}$.
You invented already a graphical representation for this kind of graphs.

Answer (score 2):

The [paper](https://github.com/sbgn/entity-relationships/blob/master/sbgn_ER-level1.pdf) linked from comments describes **3** types of components:

1. Entities (represented by `v` nodes in your chart)
2. Statements (`e1` & `e2`)
3. Influences (`e3` & `e4`)

One way to represent this is to define a *graph tower*:
level one graph $G_1$ is a graph with vertices $V_1$ and edges $E_1$.
Level $n$ graph $G_n$ is a graph with vertices $V_n=V_{n-1}\cup
E_{n-1}$ and edges $E_n$.

In your case the tower has just two levels:

1. E/S level 1 graph with nodes=entities and edges=statements
2. ES/I level 2 graph with nodes=elements of the E/S graph and edges=influences

PS. The reason to define the the *graph tower* in terms of traditional
graphs is that those have been studied for long time, there are many
theorems and algorithms about them, and they can be built upon in your
study/manipulation of *graph tower*.

Comment: Thank you for interesting solution, I vote up for this. But still, for me the ideal solution seems to consider the described object as it is, be it not a graph. I believe some papers in some math or applied areas exist regarding this kind of object, and also exist the name for it. That would be the best scenario, as then I could reference to these works in my article I write now, and the model/name would be justified. Taking in account I need to extend this model with some complications, necessary to fully match and represent textually all three languages of SBGN - it is very desired.

Comment: Oops, still not enough points for voting -((

Comment: @denis.shirshov: you need min point for downvoting, not upvoting. you can also [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/215439).